# Cannot access redux object array property

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm fairly new to react/redux and I have an unexpected issue that I can't understand

I retrieve a specific article from redux, the action is fired when I load the correct page. I can see in redux dev tools that the article is correctly loaded in `state.article` everything is working fine.

Reducer (simplified) :

```
const initialState = {
  article: null,
  loading: true,
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case GET_TARGET_ARTICLE:
      return {
        ...state,
        article: payload,
        loading: false
      };

}
```

Action :

```
export const getTargetArticle = slug => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("api/article/" + slug);
    dispatch({
      type: GET_TARGET_ARTICLE,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    ...
  }
};
```

Here is what the article object is supposed to have :

```
article: {
   title:"",
   content: "",
   comments:[],
}
```

**Issue :** As I said, `state.article` is correctly populated and I can access `title` and `content`. But when I try to access the comments, I get a nasty `Cannot read property 'comments' of null`. Any idea why ?

Here is how I display it if it helps :

```
const Article = ({ getTargetArticle, article: { article, loading }, match }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getTargetArticle(match.params.slug);
  }, []);

  let commentsList = article.comments.map((comment, index) => (
    <Fragment>{comment.title}</Fragment>
  ));

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {article && article.title}
      {commentsList}
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At initial render comments will only have empty array so you can't iterator through it and there will be no title inside comments. So, comment.title is causing you the issue. To resolve this, check it before using map:

```
  let commentsList = article.comments.length && 
    article.comments.map((comment, index) => (
    <Fragment>{comment.title}</Fragment>
  ));
```

You may also check for title:

```
<Fragment>{comment.title && comment.title || ''}</Fragment>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was it! (just had to check if article exists instead of article.comments.length though)